# Entity framework - create the csdl, ssdl and msl files

Tags: entity-framework, edmx

I work with EF 4 (not with Self-tracking entities currently). I've added some columns (non of them is a key and all of the are nullable) to one of my entities, and got the `Number of members in conceptual type does not match with number of members on object side type` exception.
I've followed the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096399/number-of-members-in-conceptual-type-does-not-match-with-number-of-members-on-obj) but all I got from that was that this entity does not appear in my edmx anymore. I've re-added it from DB, but I keep getting the same exception.
I think the problem is that I've copied the csdl/ssdl/msl files to my executing assembly directory. I'd like to copy the updated files, but they're not created again (they were once created in the `obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed` folder of my EF project), not even after removing them.
Any way to get those files created again?
Thanks.

P.S: As I don't want to publish excess amounts of code, I don't add anything yet but I'll be happy to add needed information, I'm just not sure what exactly is needed.

Comment: I did the same as [Noich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427653/noich) but instead of selecting `Embed in Output Assembly` I selected `Copy To Output Directory` and it worked for me

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So if you want to create the csdl, ssdl amd msl files, do the following:

1. Go to your edmx file.
2. Click on the GuI screen that shows the model.
3. Switch to the property window (I didn't know that it needs to be accessed from the GUI area and not by right clicking the file in the Solution Explorer.
4. In the `Metadata Artifact Process` select `Embed in Output Assembly`.

Done and done, the files will appear in `Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed` under `obj` or `obj\x86`, depends on your build definitions.
I'm sorry if this seems to simple to explain, but I was in need for those instructions (msdn was not a great help) and I hope it might help others.

Comment: It is good answer so i will give you vote and It is available on msdn or not?

Comment: I'm not sure it's in MSDN. It was a while ago, but I think it was another developer at work that assisted me with that.

Comment: This also works if you are having problems with your CSDL, MSL, and SSDL files not being published to the bin directory using VS Publish. :)

Comment: What happens if you don't have an edmx file?